# Which one of the following are true?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, analyticity, cauchy-riemann-equations

> Consider the function $e^{-z^{-4}}$  for $z≠0$ and $f(0)=0$. Then,
>
> (A) $f$ is not analytic.
>
> (B)$f$ is not differentiable at $z=0.$
>
> (c)$f$ does not satisfy the C-R(Cauchy-Riemann) equation.
>
> (d)$f$ satisfies the C-R(Cauchy-Riemann) equation and not analytic.

(A) $f$ is not analytic. $(A)$is False.  Laurentz series expansion has principle part.

(B) $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{-h^{-4}}}{h}.$$ Let $h=u+iv$,

**Path 1:** Along real axis. $$\lim_{u\to 0^+}\frac{e^{-u^{-4}}}{u}=0.$$
$$\lim_{u\to 0^-}\frac{e^{-u^{-4}}}{u}=0.$$

**Path 2:** Along the imaginary axis. $$\lim_{v\to 0}\frac{e^{-v^{-4}}}{iv}=0.$$

I am not able to disprove the differentiability. I tried to prove $$ |\frac{f(z)}{z}|^2=|\frac{e^{-z^{-4}}}{z}|^2=\frac{e^{-z^{-4}}}{z}\overline{\frac{e^{-z^{-4}}}{z}}=\frac{e^{-z^{-4}-\overline{z^{-4}}}}{|z|^2}$$. I have no Idea how to prove it.

(C) For C-R equation. I need to check whether $$if_x=f_y.$$ $$f(x,y)=e^{-z^{-4}}$$ $$=e^{-\frac{1}{(x+iy)^4}}$$ $$=e^{-\frac{(x-iy)^4}{(x^2+y^2)^4}}$$

I got $$f_x=e^{-\frac{(x-iy)^4}{(x^2+y^2)^4}}\frac{(x^2+y^2)^44(x-iy)^3-(x-iy)^48x(x^2+y^2)^3}{(x^2+y^2)^8}$$

$$f_y=e^{-\frac{(x-iy)^4}{(x^2+y^2)^4}}\frac{(x^2+y^2)^44(x-iy)^3(-i)-(x-iy)^4 8y(x^2+y^2)^3}{(x^2+y^2)^8}$$. $if_x\neq f_y$. C-R equation won't satisfy. How do I prove $f(z)$ is differentiable at $z=0$?

Comment: Take $z=re^{i\pi/4}$, with $r>0$. Then $f(z)=\exp(-z^{-4})=\exp(1/r^4)\to\infty$ as $r\to0^+$. Therefore, $f$ is unbounded near $z=0$. It can't be complex-differentiable, differentiable, or even continuous. If you take $z=r>0$ and compute that $f(r)=e^{-1/r^4}\to0$ for $r\to0^+$ then you show that $f$ cannot even be made continuous at $z=0$ as a function returning values on the Riemann sphere.

Comment: Or you can apply directly [Casorati-Weiertrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casorati%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) to conclude that because $f$ is meromorphic on a punctured neighborhood of $z=0$ and at $z=0$ it doesn't have either a pole or a removable singularity (the principal part of the Laurent expansion is non-zero and has infinitely many terms), then near $z=0$ the function $f$ takes a set of values that is dense on the plane. No chance of being continuous.

Comment: You have computed $f_x$ and $f_y$ at points $z=\neq 0$. To compute them at $z=0$ you will need to go directly from the definition $f_x(0,0)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^{-1/h^4}}{h}=0$ and $f_y(0,0)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(0,h)-f(0,0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^{-1/h^4}}{h}=0$. Since all partial derivatives vanish at $z=0$, then Cauchy-Riemann equations do hold at that point.

Comment: at $z=0$ ,$$if_x(0,0)=i0=0=f_y(0,0)$$. right? @HGLandcaster

Comment: Yes. But notice that you shouldn't deduce it from the formulas that you computed above. Those are for points different from $z=0$. The partial derivatives at $z=0$ ought to be computed directly from the definition of partial derivative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $\zeta_4$ a $4$-th root of $-1$ and for $\epsilon >0$, $z_\epsilon = \zeta_4 \epsilon$. You have $$
\lim\limits_{\epsilon \to 0}f(z_\epsilon) = \lim\limits_{\epsilon \to 0}e^{-z_\epsilon^{-4}} = \lim\limits_{\epsilon \to 0}e^{1/\epsilon^4} = \infty.$$

Therefore $f$ is not even continuous at $0$.

Hence:

- $f$ is not analytic.
- Not differentiable at $0$.
- Satisfy the Cauchy Riemann equation for $z\neq 0$ as $f$ is analytic for $z \neq 0$.

Comment: But I am not getting $if_x =f_y$. why?

Comment: was my $f_x$ and $f_y$ wrong?

Comment: They are indeed wrong. At least a sign error. However, you still have to make some factorization to verify that $i f_x = f_y$.

Comment: Thank you. Let me do again.

Comment: Clarification on the last bullet: Cauchy-Riemann equations only imply complex differentiability once real differentiability is known, a function might be non-(real)differentiable and still satisfy Cauchy-Riemann equations at a point.

Comment: @HGLandcaster You're right. I'll remove last point as more investigation is required regarding real differentiability at the origin.

Comment: From what I see, this function **does** satisfy the Cauchy Riemann equations at $z=0$. @N.Maneesh In your question you computed partial derivatives at points $z\neq0$, but if you compute the partial derivatives at $z=0$, I think you would get $0$ for all of them. Therefore, Cauchy-Riemann equations hold at that point.

Comment: Interesting! A kind of counterexample that I may use!